# How to display many fields' values with ForeignKey relationship?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Looking for solution of this problem I encountered some similar threads, but referring to older versions of Django/DRF and thus not working in my case.

There are these two models:

```py
class CsdModel(models.Model):
   model_id = models.CharField("Item ID", max_length=8, primary_key=True)
   name = models.CharField("Item Name", max_length=40)
   active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.model_id


class CsdListing(models.Model):
   model_id = models.ForeignKey(CsdModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=0, related_name='m_id')
   name = models.ForeignKey(CsdModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=0, related_name='m_name')
   (...)
```

EDIT: Serializers are defined this way:

```py
class CsdModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   model_id = serializers.RegexField(regex='^\w{2}\d{3}$', allow_blank=False)
   name = serializers.CharField(min_length=6, max_length=50, allow_blank=False)

   class Meta:
      model = CsdModel
      fields = '__all__'


class CsdListingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   session_id = serializers.RegexField(regex='^s\d{2}$', allow_blank=False)

   def validate_session_id(self, value):
      (...)

   class Meta:
      model = CsdListing
      fields = '__all__'
```

What I'd like to see, is `model_id` and `name` from `CsdModel` displayed inside a form created based on `CsdListing` model. But instead, the ID is duplicated:

[image: Form Capture]

How should I rebuild the model(s) to have both ID and name displayed in the form?

Comment: You don't need two foreign keys. But please show your serializers.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: added, as requested.

Answer (score 0):

You should have only one foreign key. But the listing serializer should then reference the model as a nested serializer.

```
class CsdListing(models.Model):
   model = models.ForeignKey(CsdModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=0, related_name='listing')

class CsdListingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   model = CsdModelSerializer()
   session_id = serializers.RegexField(regex='^s\d{2}$', allow_blank=False)
```

Comment: It solves the problem partially. Now I can see blank fields of nested `CsdListing` model (wished to see dropdown list with all saved records), but trying to post any data invokes AssertionError: `The '.create()' method does not support writable nested fields by default. Write an explicit '.create()' method for serializer 'core.serializers.CsdListingSerializer', or set 'read_only=True' on nested serializer fields.`